# how to change visibility a view in a fragment from the activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, visibility

As stated in the title how can change visibility a view in a fragment from the activity?

My code has a launch activity and a fragment. I want to change the visibility of a view inside fragment from activity.

How can do this?

Answer (score 1):

There can be a couple of ways. It would nice if you add some code for the reference.
1st way would be to have a method in the fragment which would have the set the visibility to gone in fragment. In you activity you can get the instance of the fragment by this `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(<container - id>)` and then just call the fragment method.

2nd way could be using interface to this.